# Eucalyptus Cloud Setup

Tags: eucalyptus

Setting up [eucalyptus cloud](http://www.eucalyptus.com/) on my laptop has become a nightmare for me.

When I run the command `euca-describe-availability-zones`, it shows up as expected. It shows all free/max values correctly. However, when I run `euca-run-instance` it says that no resources av.

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

you are not giving enough information to really understand what the problem is. If you check on the sticky post at http://open.eucalyptus.com/forums/eucalyptus-support-0 for generic info needed. In your case, can you post the output of euca-describe-availability-zones verbose (ran with the admin credentials) and the output of euca-describe-addresses (again with admin credentials)?

cheers
graziano